# Search method to show record before data update in sql server Angularjs asp.netmvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, updates, execution

Angular js function updating some record. After updating record i am calling search method to show data on view.

But record does not updated before that search method call that does not get data so show null on view.

I have separate button for search on its ng-click this search method call. After some second if i click that button it shows data on view.

my code is,

```
vm.Update = function (value)
    {
        var test = value;
        searchCriteria = {
            From: vm.From,
            To: vm.To,
            Region: vm.Region,
            City: vm.SelectedCity
        }        
        surveyService.UpdateVisit(searchCriteria,value).then(function (d) {
            var Confrm = JSON.parse(d.data.data);
            if (d.data.status) {
                toastr.success(Updated, {
                    autoDismiss: false
                });
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(errorMsg);
            }
        });
        vm.searchVisit(0);
    }
```

This searchvisit call and service unable to update data in database so i do not get any record on view. When i call this searchvisit method from separate button for searching it shows record with updated data.

Hopes for your suggestions how to pause execution before calling searchvisit method or any alternative that it gets any response than move execution control to searchvisit method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous nature in JS.

From your code, `surveyService.UpdateVisit(searchCriteria,value)` returns a promise. Thus, when `vm.searchVisit(0);` is called, `surveyService.UpdateVisit(searchCriteria,value)` has not been resolved yet, meaning updating is still in progress and have not been completed. There for  `vm.searchVisit(0);` shows records that are not updated.

If your second function is dependent on the values of the first function call, please add it as shown below inside the success callback.

```
surveyService.UpdateVisit(searchCriteria,value).then(function (d) {
        var Confrm = JSON.parse(d.data.data);
        if (d.data.status) {
            toastr.success(Updated, {
                autoDismiss: false
            });
        }
        else {
            toastr.error(errorMsg);
        }
        //Add this here. 
        vm.searchVisit(0);
    });
```

Comment: i actually tried this before because i had same idea in my head but at that time it was not working for me. But know i try again it works may be i add toaster later on. but thanks for your help.